# How to debug a deadlock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock

Other than that I don't know if I can reproduce it now that it's happened (I've been using this particular application for a week or two now without issue), assuming that I'm running my application in the VS debugger, how should I go about debugging a deadlock after it's happened? I thought I might be able to get at call stacks if I paused the program and hence see where the different threads were when it happened, but clicking pause just threw Visual Studio into a deadlock too till I killed my application.

Is there some way other than browsing through my source tree to find potential problems? Is there a way to get at the call stacks once the problem has occured to see where the problem is? Any other tools/tips/tricks that might help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you did was the correct way. If Visual Studio also deadlocks, that happens now and then. It's just bad luck, unless there's some other issue.

You don't have to run the application in the debugger in order to debug it. Run the application normally, and if the deadlock happens, you can attach VS later. **Ctrl+Alt+P**, select the process, choose debugger type and click **attach**. Using a different set of debugger types might reduce the risk of VS crashing (especially if you don't debug native code)

A deadlock involves 2 or more threads. You probably know the first one (probably your UI thread) since you noticed the deadlock in your application. Now you only need to find the other one. With knowledge of the architecture, it should be easy to find (e.g. what other threads use the same locks, interact with the UI etc)

If VS doesn't work *at all*, you can always use **windbg**. Download here: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: If your deadlock disappears as soon as you open the tools to look for it, you may need to modify your program to help out.  What you can do is start another thread in your program whose only job is to figure out when the deadlock is happening and then throw an Exception or call a debugger break so that your deadlock state is preserved for you to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try different approaches in the following order:

- First, inspect the code to look for thread-safety violations, making sure that your critical regions don't call other functions that will in turn try to lock a critical region.
- Use whatever tool you can get your hands on to visualize thread activity, I use an in-house perl script that parses an OS log we made and graphs all the context switches and shows when a thread gets pre-empted.
- If you can't find a good tool, do some logging to see the last threads that were running before the deadlock occurred. This will give you a clue as to where the issue might be caused, it helps if the locking mechanisms have unique names, like if an object has it's own thread, create a dedicated semaphore or mutex just to manage that thread.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different programs like Intel(R) Parallel Inspector:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-parallel-inspector/

Such programs can show you places in your code with potential deadlocks. However you should pay for it, or use it only evaluation period. Don't know if there is any free tools like this.

Comment: It seems to only be for C/C++ too (unmanaged I assume, since there is no managed C as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 0):

Just like anywhere, there're no "Silver bullet" tools to catch all the deadlocks. It is all about the sequence in which different threads aquire resources so your job is to find out where the order was violated. Usually Visual Studio or other debugger will provide stack traces and you will be able to find out where the discrepancy is. DevPartner Studio does provide deadlock analysis but last time I've checked there were too many false positives. Some static analysis tools will find some potential deadlocks too.

Other than that it helps to get the architecture straight to enforce resource aquisition order. For example, layering helps to make sure upper level locks are taken before lower ones but beware of callbacks.